# (staticfiles.W004) The directory in the STATICFILES_DIRS setting does not exist error in django

Tags: python, django, django-templates

so i am working on a project where i want to use some css files. but i couldn't link them with my html page in django. i've used everything i knew but still static is not loading

my error is:

```
 (staticfiles.W004) The directory 'C:\Users\ASUS\PycharmProjects\e-payment\epayment\static' in the STATICFILES_DIRS setting does not exist.
```

my code snippets are given below:
my setting is:

**settings.py**

```py
Django settings for epayment project.

Generated by 'django-admin startproject' using Django 4.1.1.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/settings/

For the full list of settings and their values, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/settings/
"""

from pathlib import Path
import os

# Build paths inside the project like this: BASE_DIR / 'subdir'.
BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = 'django-insecure-+)&^ze^f+g#k28j#(1&r8y@u)g4=9!g7c4ef-i07!5@yhq2dd3'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [

    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'epayapp',


]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'epayment.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': ['templates'],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'epayment.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': BASE_DIR / 'db.sqlite3',
    }
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = 'static/'

STATICFILES_DIRS = [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static")]
# Default primary key field type
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/settings/#default-auto-field

DEFAULT_AUTO_FIELD = 'django.db.models.BigAutoField'
```

here'e my base file that i am using

**base.html**

```py
    <!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>{% block title%} {% endblock %}</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static '/epayapp/main.css'%}" type="text/css">
    {% load static%}
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/common-styles.css">
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-iYQeCzEYFbKjA/T2uDLTpkwGzCiq6soy8tYaI1GyVh/UjpbCx/TYkiZhlZB6+fzT" crossorigin="anonymous">



  </head>

 <style>


   nav {
              background-color: orange;
            }

        h2 {
            font-family: "PT Serif";
        }
        h4 {
            font-weight: 900;
        }

        #curr_bal {
            border: 4px solid;
            border-radius: 100px;
        }

        .current {
            border: 1px solid;
            padding: 3px;
        }
        .curr_bal {
            font-family: "Cinzel";
            font-weight: 600;
        }

      .col-sm-3
      {
      display: inline-block;
      margin-left: -4px;

     {% block css %} {% endblock %}
  </style>

<body>

  {% block body %}
  {% endblock %}

    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-u1OknCvxWvY5kfmNBILK2hRnQC3Pr17a+RTT6rIHI7NnikvbZlHgTPOOmMi466C8" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@popperjs/core@2.11.6/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-oBqDVmMz9ATKxIep9tiCxS/Z9fNfEXiDAYTujMAeBAsjFuCZSmKbSSUnQlmh/jp3" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.1/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-7VPbUDkoPSGFnVtYi0QogXtr74QeVeeIs99Qfg5YCF+TidwNdjvaKZX19NZ/e6oz" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    {% block script %} {% endblock %}
</body>
</html>
```

my css file that i want to link with

**main.css**

```py
    
 body {
            background-color: floralwhite;
        }
```

thanks in advance

Comment: Try removing that first slash `{% static '/epayapp/main.css'%}` -> `{% static 'epayapp/main.css'%}` and that main.css file should be located in `(root)/epayapp/static/epayapp/main.css` & then run `python manage.py collectstatic` (even tho it shouldn't be needed in dev envs)

Answer (score 1):

you need to simply create a folder with a name with which the error has caused, In simple words you need to create a folder named by static in your following path which is also shown in error itslef "(staticfiles.W004) The directory 'C:\Users\ASUS\PycharmProjects\e-payment\epayment\static' in the STATICFILES_DIRS setting does not exist.", the static folder is missing therefore the problem was invoked, i also had the same error "?: (staticfiles.W004) The directory '/home/mrnecro/dj_social/bffbook/static_project' in the STATICFILES_DIRS setting does not exist." so subsequently i did the same, i just created the the folder named by static_project and restarted the server again and the problem was gone!

Thankyou, hope this may help you, do comment if its not.

Comment: or either just change the path of the folder in settings where you have mentioned it.

Answer (score 1):

This error occurs because you have not created a static folder on the given path 'C:\Users\ASUS\PycharmProjects\e-payment\epayment\static'

Please check the path of the static folder. You make this folder outside or some other place.

Answer (score 0):

The "The directory in the STATICFILES_DIRS setting does not exist" error in Django occurs when Django can't find the directory specified in the STATICFILES_DIRS setting in your project's settings file. This setting is used to specify additional directories where Django should look for static files, in addition to the app directories specified in the STATICFILES_FINDERS setting.

To fix this error, you should check the following:

Make sure that the directory specified in the STATICFILES_DIRS setting actually exists in your project's file system. You can do this by navigating to the directory using your operating system's file explorer or command line interface.

Check that you have specified the correct path to the directory in the STATICFILES_DIRS setting. The path should be relative to the base directory of your Django project.

Ensure that the directory has the necessary permissions to be accessed by your Django application.

Finally, you may need to restart your Django development server after making changes to your settings file.

Once you have checked these things, you should be able to resolve the error and Django will be able to find your static files.